# time downsampling vs. frequency downsampling

Tags: dft

$x[n]_M$ is a finite length sequence of length M.

if:

$$
y = x[nN]_M    \tag{1}
$$

is called **downsampling in the time-domain**.

then what do you call the process of converting going from a M-point to an N-point DFT?

$$
y[n] = \Bigg[ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n-Nk]_M \Bigg] R_N[n] \tag{2}
$$

does that have a name?  like **frequency downsampling**? **frequency rebinning**...**frequency re-pie cutting** or something like that?
just guessing...

($R_N[n]$ = window function, which is 1 between 0 and N-1 and 0 otherwise.)

$$
Y[k]_N = X(e^{j\omega})\bigg|_{\omega=2\pi k/N} \tag{3}
$$

rebinning $Y[k]_N$ to $Y[k]_M$ for example.

>

Comment: maybe call it "frequency rebinning" for lack of a better name? then its a choice of "up binning" or "down binning"?

Comment: I'd recommend removing the window function; it adds nothing to this question, but makes it harder to argue based on the "pure" DFT; anyways, the formula for $y[n]$ that you wrote has nothing to do with a DFT; not quite sure where you're taking use here.

Comment: yeah... I know what you mean... the window function is driving me crazy also... connection with DFT is apparently because this is the time-domain representation of doing the same "rebinning" operation in the DFT domain.... of taking the unit circle apple pie and cutting it up for 3 people instead of 6 people, nevermind if we need to put two pieces of pie on top of the other because of  aliasing...

Comment: I'm just going to call it rebinning in my notes… other people can say I don't know #$@#$ later....

Comment: on second thought, I think the operation is called "resampling-DFT of a finite length sequence"

Comment: it's definitely not resampling.

Answer (score 0):

Your second equation suggests that $y[n]$ is obtained by performing an $N$-point inverse DFT of an $M$-point DFT $X[k]$ of an $M$-point sequence $x[n]$.

The result can be interpreted as **shifted** copies of $x[n]$ are superimposed, causing possible aliasing in time, which depends on whether $ N \geq M$ or $N < M$.

If $N \geq M$, there is no aliasing and $y[n]$ will be an $N$ point sequence whose first $M$ samples will be identical to $x[n]$ for $n=0,1,...,M-1$ and remaining $N-M$ samples will be zero-padded.

$$
y[n] = \begin{cases} { x[n] ~~~,~~~ n = 0,1,...,M-1 \\ ~~~~~0 ~~~,~~~ n= M,M+1,...N-1} \end{cases}
$$

Otherwise if $N < M$, then $y[n]$ will be a **time-aliased** version of $x[n]$, as shifted copies of $x[n]$ would be **overlapping** each other. If you want any non-aliased samples in $y[n]$, then $N > M/2$ in general and in such a case $y[n]$ could be defined as:

$$
y[n] = \begin{cases} { x[n]+x[n+N] ~~~, n = 0,1,...,M-N \\ x[n] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~,~~~ n= M-N+1,...,N-1 } \end{cases}
$$